# Bluetooth mouse lagging while using bluetooth headphones microphone

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, microphone, headphones, wireless-mouse

I have the following problem occuring on both Windows and MacBook - when I'm trying to use bluetooth headphones microphone, mouse start lagging. The situation doesn't occur when I only use headphones (without microphone) for example using Spotify or YouTube. However, when starting a conversation on Zoom or Google Meets, using microphone of bluetooth headphones makes bluetooth mouse lagging. When I switch microphone to internal MacBook or Windows microphone and only use bluetooth headphones to listen, it works fine.
The devices are as follows:

- Headphones - Xiaomi Mi True Wireless Earphones 2 Basic
- Mouse - Samsung S Action

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with my Sony WH-1000XM3 and Logitech G604. It was connected when changing to the Headset BT profile when connecting to a meeting.

**I have resolved the issue for now by unpairing and pairing again the BT headphones.** Now I do not have any mouse lag and do not suffer from any kind of low sound quality. I hope the issue will not appear again and that it will work out for you as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my Sony WH-XB700 headphones and a Steelseries Rival 3 Wireless mouse, connected through Bluetooth to my Dell Precision 5530 laptop.

**The solution was unpairing and pairing the headphones again.** Given that the other answer suggest the same happened with some other Sony headphones model and I have also paired some Philips headphones but didn't experience the same issue, I'm inclined to believe the issue might be specific to Sony's headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with Headset Huawei Freelace pro and mouse Lenovo Silent BT Mouse. In my case, unpairing and pairing the **mouse** again worked, but only temporarily unfortunately.

Note that the problem really appeared while using the headset in a MS Teams call. It didn't occur while only listening to music.